# Mountain bike trainer tires

Tags: trainer

I received a trainer that fits my mountain bike. I am trying to find a tire that is quiet.

I can't find any online that are the same size as my current tire which is 26 x 2.25. I found only one close which is the WTB ThickSlick Comp tire 26 x 2.0. No real trainer tires at my size.

Any recommendations on trainer tires at this size? or will a 2.00 tire fit on a rim that holds a 2.25?

Answer (score 3):

On a trainer that supports the bike, normal tire rules do not apply, as the tires don't have to support the mass of you and the bike, nor provide any lateral grip.

How narrow tire you can drop down to depends on the actual width of the rim, not the width of the original equipment tires. You can probably fit a tire that is not much wider the the outside width of the rim.

I've run a 1.5" hybrid bike tire on a MTB wheel on a trainer with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

To get a quieter tyre for your trainer, you want one without any knobs at all, and ideally no tread.  So, an otherwise worn-out tyre is perfect.  Width is irrelevant on a trainer, and you're unlikely to puncture.

If you're on a budget, check out your local bike coop for a donor tyre.

You could even buy the cheapest nastiest 26" tyre and then cut and sand the knobs off the middle line.  Note this is easier with a grinder, but makes an enormous mess.